# Get ID of clicked element Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I have 7 `<li>` elements and when I click on someone, I would like to log name of ID, this is working, but only for first element, and always alerting `tab-1` , when click on `tab-5` it's doesn't work, hmmm what is problem there

HTML

```
<div class="tabs is-fullwidth">
  <!-- Tabs navigation menu -->
  <ul>
    <li id="tab-1" class="tabs-heading is-active">
      Tab 1
    </li>
    <li id="tab-2" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 2
    </li>
    <li id="tab-3" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 3
    </li>
    <li id="tab-4" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 4
    </li>
    <li id="tab-5" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 5
    </li>
    <li  id="tab-6" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 6
    </li>
    <li  id="tab-7" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 7
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
document.querySelector('.tabs-heading').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: You're only attaching to the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) selects only the first matched element. You have to select all the element with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then use `forEach()` to add event (`click`) one by one.

**Working Code Example:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-heading').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="tabs is-fullwidth">
  <!-- Tabs navigation menu -->
  <ul>
    <li id="tab-1" class="tabs-heading is-active">
      Tab 1
    </li>
    <li id="tab-2" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 2
    </li>
    <li id="tab-3" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 3
    </li>
    <li id="tab-4" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 4
    </li>
    <li id="tab-5" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 5
    </li>
    <li  id="tab-6" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 6
    </li>
    <li  id="tab-7" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 7
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, works perfect, I will accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns **the first matching element** only.

You need to use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead and bind the event listener by looping over the fetched collection.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-heading')
  .forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert(this.id);
    })
  });
```

```html
<div class="tabs is-fullwidth">
  <!-- Tabs navigation menu -->
  <ul>
    <li id="tab-1" class="tabs-heading is-active">
      Tab 1
    </li>
    <li id="tab-2" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 2
    </li>
    <li id="tab-3" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 3
    </li>
    <li id="tab-4" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 4
    </li>
    <li id="tab-5" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 5
    </li>
    <li id="tab-6" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 6
    </li>
    <li id="tab-7" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 7
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` only selects the first element which matches the query. You will either have to use `querySelectorAll` and register the listener on all elements or use Event Delegation to handle it at the `ul` (or some other parent) level.

**Using `querySelectorAll`:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-heading').forEach(function(li) {
  li.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="tabs is-fullwidth">
  <!-- Tabs navigation menu -->
  <ul>
    <li id="tab-1" class="tabs-heading is-active">
      Tab 1
    </li>
    <li id="tab-2" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 2
    </li>
    <li id="tab-3" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 3
    </li>
    <li id="tab-4" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 4
    </li>
    <li id="tab-5" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 5
    </li>
    <li id="tab-6" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 6
    </li>
    <li id="tab-7" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 7
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Using Event Delegation**

```js
document.querySelector('div.tabs ul').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (target.className.indexOf('tabs-heading') > -1) {
    alert(target.id);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="tabs is-fullwidth">
  <!-- Tabs navigation menu -->
  <ul>
    <li id="tab-1" class="tabs-heading is-active">
      Tab 1
    </li>
    <li id="tab-2" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 2
    </li>
    <li id="tab-3" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 3
    </li>
    <li id="tab-4" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 4
    </li>
    <li id="tab-5" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 5
    </li>
    <li id="tab-6" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 6
    </li>
    <li id="tab-7" class="tabs-heading">
      Tab 7
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```